# Aapt error 20, Not is a Directory

Tags: java, android, excepciones

tengo un pequeño error con el aapt... He estado investigando sobre cómo usar el aapt en android con Java etc. Ya tengo todo listo pero a la hora de usarlo me dice:

```
Num: aapt
Exception:
Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.test.aapt/files/tmp/aapt-arm": error=20, Not a directory
```

Método principal:

```
String aaptPath = new File(getFilesDir(), "tmp").getAbsolutePath();

                        String sdkPath = "/storage/emulated/0/testAapt/sdk/android.jar";

                        String srcPath = "/storage/emulated/0/testAapt/src";

                        String resPath = "/storage/emulated/0/testAapt/src/main/res";

                        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

                        a.add(aaptPath + File.separator + "aapt-arm");

                        a.add("package");

                        a.add("-f");

                        a.add("-I");

                        a.add(sdkPath);

                        a.add("-J");

                        a.add(srcPath);

                        a.add("-m");

                        a.add("-M");

                        a.add("AndroidManifest.xml");

                        a.add("-S");

                        a.add(resPath);

                        a.add("-v");

                        copyAssets("aapt-arm", new File(aaptPath));
                        
                        execute(new String[]{"chmod", "-R", "744", aaptPath});
                        
                        execute(a);

                    }catch(Exception e){

                        err(e, "Main");
                        
                    }
```

Método execute:

```
private void execute(ArrayList<String> args){
        
        Process process;
        
        ProcessBuilder pro = new ProcessBuilder(args);
        
        try{
            
        process = pro.start();  
        
        ...

        }catch(Exception e){
            
        err(e, "aapt");
            
        }
    }
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código en la pregunta

Comment: Intenta colocando la parte del código relacionada a tu pregunta, donde se realiza la llamada de la función o metodo involucrado.